# pst-solides3d and hidden lines

Tags: pstricks, 3d

I am trying to draw figures with `pstricks` for the first time. Unfortunately, I am struggling with it. I was trying to draw a pentagon-cone and an octahedron using `pst-solides3d`, but it draws some lines dashed which actually are not hidden. I used this code:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=25 8 5,Decran=50} 
\psSolid[object=new, 
action=draw, 
sommets= 
0 0 0
0.343561 1.05737 1
-0.899454 0.653491 1
-0.899454 -0.653491 1
0.343561 -1.05737 1
1.11179 0 1, 
faces={  
[0 1 2]
[0 2 3]
[0 3 4]
[0 4 5]
[0 5 1]
[ 1 2 3 4 5]}]% 
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=25 8 5,Decran=100}
\psSolid[object=new, 
action=draw, 
sommets= 
%n=4
0 0 0 %0
0.420448 0.420448 0.5 %e1
-0.420448 0.420448 0.5 %e2
-0.420448 -0.420448 0.5 %e3
0.420448 -0.420448 0.5 %e4
0 0 1, %u 
faces={
[0 1 4]
[0 1 2]
[0 2 3]
[0 3 4]
[2 3 5]
[3 4 5]
[1 2 5]
[1 4 5]}]% 
\end{pspicture}
```

The result, however, looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HTNa.jpg]

Obiously, lines which should be dashed (because they are hidden) are not and some lines which should be continuous are dashed. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

---

Thanks for your answers. There is still something strange.
If I set `num=all`, like in the code

```
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=25 12 5,Decran=100}
%\axesIIID[showOrigin=false](1,1,1)(3,2,2.5)
\psSolid[object=new, 
action=draw*,
fillcolor=red,
opacity=.6,
fcol=8 (Blue),
num=all,
sommets= 
%n=4
0 0 0 %0
0.420448 0.420448 0.5 %e1
-0.420448 0.420448 0.5 %e2
-0.420448 -0.420448 0.5 %e3
0.420448 -0.420448 0.5 %e4
0 0 1 %u
0 1.18921 1 %w1
-1.18921 0 1 %w2
0 -1.18921 1 %w3
1.18921 0 1, %w4
faces={
[0 1 4]
[0 2 1]
[0 3 2]
[0 4 3]
[2 3 5]
[3 4 5]
[1 2 5]
[1 5 4]
[6 7 8 9]}]% 
\end{pspicture}
```

then I get the following result: [image: wrong numbering]
which is obviously not as intended. How can I fix this?

Comment: You know, that there are ready made objects for a cone and octahedron?

Comment: @Herbert: I converted the OP's "answer" to an question edit. You might want to re-add your recent comment.

Comment: `...,num=all,numsep=2pt,...`. However, it would make more sense to define your object as two solids

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `action` key of [`pst-solides3d`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d) defines how the object is drawn:

- `none`: nothing is drawn.
- `draw`: draws the solid as a framework and sets up dashed lines for the hidden edges.
- `draw*`: draws the solid with dashed lines for the hidden edges and colours the visible faces.
- `draw**`: draws the solid with a painting algorithm, without the hidden edges and with colouration of the visible faces.

Using `action=draw**`, your document produces the following visibly incomplete polyhedra:

[image]

Although the edges of the faces make for a complete visual drawing, there are some missing faces. Now, you may notice that they formed part of your code, but they need to conform to the face specification (from the [`pst-solides3d` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf)):

> ...a face is characterized by a list of the indices of it's vertices,
>   listed in counter-clockwise order when the face is viewed from the
>   exterior of the solid.

The easiest way to find out the order (and which direction is clockwise or counter-clockwise) is to add the key-value `num=all` and `show=all` to your `\psSolid` object. That is, use

```
\psSolid[action=draw,num=all,show=all,...]
```

This numbers all the vertices (`sommets`) and all the faces (`faces`). Rewriting the faces in the correct counter-clockwise fashion produce the expected results:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=25 8 5,Decran=50} 
\psSolid[object=new,%num=all,show=all,
  action=draw,
  sommets= 
    0 0 0
    0.343561 1.05737 1
    -0.899454 0.653491 1
    -0.899454 -0.653491 1
    0.343561 -1.05737 1
    1.11179 0 1, 
  faces={%
    [0 1 5]
    [0 5 4]
    [0 4 3]
    [0 3 2]
    [0 2 1]
    [1 2 3 4 5]}]% 
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=25 8 5,Decran=100}
\psSolid[object=new, 
  action=draw,%num=all,show=all,
  sommets= 
    0 0 0 %0
    0.420448 0.420448 0.5 %e1
    -0.420448 0.420448 0.5 %e2
    -0.420448 -0.420448 0.5 %e3
    0.420448 -0.420448 0.5 %e4
    0 0 1, %u 
  faces={
    [0 2 1]
    [0 1 4]
    [0 4 3]
    [0 3 2]
    [5 1 2]
    [5 2 3]
    [5 3 4]
    [5 4 1]}]% 
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Thank you, Werner, your answer is perfect. But there is still one thing that does not work as expected, see my answer below.

Comment: @TomJonathan: What is wrong with your code? You mention it is "not as intended", but I don't see anything wrong with it. Note that the vertex numbers are displaced quite a distance away from each node... in 3D space. So, it may look scattered. If you want the numbers to be closer to the nodes, you need to place them closer *manually*. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @TomJonathan: Herbert had made an earlier comment to use `...,numfaces=all,numsep=2pt,...` in order to have the vertex numbers set closer to the numbers.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you. I've read that and I have tested it; it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Using the object octahedron:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=25 8 5,Decran=50} 
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(3,3) 
\psSolid[object=octahedron, a=1, hue=0.2 0.6]
\end{pspicture}
%
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2,-2)(2,2) 
\psSolid[object=octahedron, a=1,
   plansepare={[0 0 1 0]},% plain to cut the object: z=0
   name=Octa, action=none]
\psSolid[object=load, load=Octa1, hue=0.2 0.6]% lower half
\psSolid[object=load, load=Octa0, hue=0.2 0.6](0,0,0.5)% upper half
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]