# How can I draw a transparent cube in 3D perspective?

Tags: pstricks, 3d

I would like to draw a transparent, `flattened cube' in perspective with dotted lines from both vanishing points to each of the vertices of the 3D solid. Is there a PSTricks package for this?

It is much like Jan Hlavacek's answer to [What is the easiest way to draw 3D cube with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-draw-3d-cube-with-tikz) but with the vanishing points and dotted lines from these, and then the `cube' should be transparent. Unfortunately I do not know TikZ.

**Update**

The following code shows what I would like to achieve:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\HAa{-5.25 }
\def\HBa{12.5 }
\def\Ab{-0.85 }
\def\Bb{3.05 }
\def\Ia{-1.8 }
\def\Ja{2.65 }
 \centering
 \psset{unit=0.765cm}
  \begin{pspicture}(\HAa,\Ab)(\HBa,\Bb)
   \pnode(!\HAa 0){H1}
   \psdot(H1)
   \pnode(!\HBa 0){H2}
   \psdot(H2)
   \pnode(!\Ia 0){P9}
   \pnode(!\Ja 0){P10}
   \pcline[linestyle=dashed](H1)(P9)
   \pcline[linestyle=dashed](P10)(H2)
   \pnode(!0 \Ab){P1}
   \pnode(!0 \Bb){P2}
   \pnode(!\Ia \HAa \Ia sub \HAa div \Ab mul){P3}
   \pnode(!\Ia \HAa \Ia sub \HAa div \Bb mul){P4}
   \pnode(!\Ja \HBa \Ja sub \HBa div \Ab mul){P5}
   \pnode(!\Ja \HBa \Ja sub \HBa div \Bb mul){P6}
   \psIntersectionPoint(H1)(P5)(H2)(P3){P7}
   \psIntersectionPoint(H1)(P6)(H2)(P4){P8}
   \multido{\i=1+1}{8}{\psdot(P\i)}
   \pcline(P1)(P2)
   \pcline(P1)(P3)
   \pcline(P2)(P4)
   \pcline(P3)(P4)
   \pcline(P1)(P5)
   \pcline(P2)(P6)
   \pcline(P5)(P6)
  \psset{linestyle=dotted}
   \pcline(P3)(H1)
   \pcline(P4)(H1)
   \pcline(P5)(H1)
   \pcline(P6)(H1)
   \pcline(P3)(H2)
   \pcline(P4)(H2)
   \pcline(P5)(H2)
   \pcline(P6)(H2)
   \pcline(P7)(P8)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like to make this drawing when knowing just the width, depth, and height of the box plus the point of view, instead of maunally calculating the `\def` values.

P.S. I do not know how to include images, sorry.

**Update 2**

I have changed the code a bit. (The `\def` names are changed and the hiddens lines in the cubiod are dashed instead of dotted.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\venstre{-5.25 }
\def\hoejre{12.5 }
\def\vinkel{-0.85 }
\def\hoejde{3.05 }
\def\dybde{-1.8 }
\def\bredde{2.65 }
 \centering
 \psset{unit=0.684cm}
  \begin{pspicture}(\venstre,\vinkel)(\hoejre,\hoejde)
   \pnode(!\venstre 0){H1}
   \pnode(!\hoejre 0){H2}
   \psdot(H1)
   \psdot(H2)
   \pnode(!\dybde 0){P9}
   \pnode(!\bredde 0){P10}
   \pcline[linestyle=dashed](H1)(P9)
   \pcline[linestyle=dashed](P10)(H2)
   \pnode(!0 \vinkel){P1}
   \pnode(!0 \hoejde){P2}
   \pnode(!\dybde \venstre \dybde sub \venstre div \vinkel mul){P3}
   \pnode(!\dybde \venstre \dybde sub \venstre div \hoejde mul){P4}
   \pnode(!\bredde \hoejre \bredde sub \hoejre div \vinkel mul){P5}
   \pnode(!\bredde \hoejre \bredde sub \hoejre div \hoejde mul){P6}
   \psIntersectionPoint(H1)(P5)(H2)(P3){P7}
   \psIntersectionPoint(H1)(P6)(H2)(P4){P8}
   \multido{\i=1+1}{8}{\psdot(P\i)}
   \pcline(P1)(P2)
   \pcline(P1)(P3)
   \pcline(P2)(P4)
   \pcline(P3)(P4)
   \pcline(P1)(P5)
   \pcline(P2)(P6)
   \pcline(P5)(P6)
  \psset{linestyle=dotted}
   \pcline(P3)(H1)
   \pcline(P4)(H1)
   \pcline(P7)(H1)
   \pcline(P8)(H1)
   \pcline(P7)(H2)
   \pcline(P8)(H2)
   \pcline(P5)(H2)
   \pcline(P6)(H2)
  \psset{linestyle=dashed}
   \pcline(P7)(P3)
   \pcline(P7)(P5)
   \pcline(P7)(P8)
   \pcline(P8)(P4)
   \pcline(P8)(P6)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update 3**

Here is what I ended up with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \psset{viewpoint=10 45 8 rtp2xyz,Decran=5}
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-5,-5)(6,12)
   \psSolid[object=point,args=6 0 1.42,name=L]
   \psSolid[object=point,args=-12 9.75 1.42,name=R]
   \psSolid[object=line,linecolor=red!40,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=2pt,args=R L]
   \psSolid[object=parallelepiped,a=4.56,b=4.56,c=3.90,RotZ=-8,fillcolor=yellow!40,name=Cube,action=draw*](0 0 2)
   \multido{\iA=0+1}{8}{%
     \psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=Cube \iA,name=C\iA]
   }
   \multido{\iA=0+1}{8}{%
     \psSolid[object=line,linecolor=blue!40,linestyle=dotted,args=L C\iA]
     \psSolid[object=line,linecolor=blue!40,linestyle=dotted,args=R C\iA]
   }
   \psSolid[object=parallelepiped,a=4.56,b=4.56,c=3.90,RotZ=-8,name=Cube,action=draw](0 0 2)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: At present, this is very much a "do-it-for-me" question.  Please edit your post to give some indication of what you've tried so far.

Comment: It was not meant as that; sorry. I really just want to know if there is a PSTricks package for doing this. (Way too many details regarding the drawing itself, I see that now.)

Comment: I think `pst-solides3d` could be of interest for you. You could have a look at [some of **Herbert**'s answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2478+[3d]), he usually provides excellent answers at a fraction of the hassle of a `TikZ` answer.

Comment: @Tom Bombadil: Arrrh, interesting! I only had a look at the pst-3d package.

Comment: I cannot find anything (for me) useful in the answers from @Herbert so I will contact him and ask if there is a package or if he has a solution.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68247/3d-axis-and-polyhedron-with-line-segment-towards-origin/68256#68256). There Herbert uses `\psSolid[object=dodecahedron`, and looking at the manual, section 3.1 (_The predefined solids and their parameters_), you can find, for instance, `cube`.

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for. It is actually a `flattened cube' (not a cube as in the manual) in a 2 vanishing points perspective, just as the example Jason Whyte has refered to.

Comment: I have come across the awesome package pst-anamorphosis (documentation at melusine.eu.org/syracuse/G/pst-anamorphosis/doc) but I do not speak French. If someone could help me create the desired result using this package, I would much appreciate it. (Maybe now someone other than @Herbert can help. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}    
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=10 60 15 rtp2xyz,Decran=5}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-5,-5)(6,12)
\psSolid[object=point,args=10 -36 0,name=L]
\psSolid[object=point,args=-36 10 0,name=R]
\psSolid[object=line,linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=2pt,args=R L]
\psSolid[object=parallelepiped,a=6,b=3,c=3,RotZ=30,name=Cube,action=draw*](0 0 2)
\multido{\iA=0+1}{8}{%
  \psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=Cube \iA,name=C\iA]}
\multido{\iA=0+1}{8}{%
  \psSolid[object=line,linecolor=blue!40,linestyle=dotted,args=L C\iA]
  \psSolid[object=line,linecolor=blue!40,linestyle=dotted,args=R C\iA]}
\psSolid[object=parallelepiped,a=6,b=3,c=3,RotZ=30,name=Cube,action=draw](0 0 2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This answer is hereby accepted.

Thank you to both Tom Bombadil and Herbert.

Comment: I was a too impressed by the code to have a proper look at it. I would like the cube to be a flattened cube, i.e., a box. The height shold be something like 90 % of both the width and depth. Is this possible?

Comment: What is a "flattened cube"?

Comment: Then it is not a cube. Use `object=parallelepiped,a=..,b=..,c=..`

Comment: Is it possible to draw the black lines (both the solid and the dotted) _after_ the blue lines? I would like the black ones to be on top, if the lines intersect. Therefore, I tried to change the order of the lines in the code, but that is not possible (do to dependencies, I guess).

Comment: draw the box twice, at the first time with `action=none` and the second time with `action=draw`. This one before `\end{pspicture}`

Comment: Perfect. _One last_ thing: How do I draw a dashed line between the two vanishing points? I tried \pcline(L)(R) but that messes everything up.

Comment: draw it also as a solid object with `linestyle=dashed, args=L R`

Comment: Hmm... I assumed that the parallelepiped would hide the dashed line (= the horizon) at the segment where the first is in front of the latter. How is this done? (After this, the drawing looks like the one I drew, i.e., I will stop now.)

Comment: if it should be a hiddenline, then you have to use `action=none,name=...` for all objects which should be drawn together with taken hidden lines and surfaces into account. AT the very end you use `\psSolid[object=fusion,base=...]` where `base` gets all defined names. You can find simple examples on http://PSTricks.tug.org

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, I don't know *pstricks*, but here's A *TikZ* solution:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (V1) at (-7,1);
\coordinate (V2) at (5,1);

\fill (V1) circle (0.05) node[left] {V1};
\fill (V2) circle (0.05) node[right] {V2};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubelength}{3}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at ($(A)!\cubelength cm!(V2)$);
\coordinate (D) at ($(A)!\cubelength cm!(V1)$);

\path[name path=BV1] (B) -- (V1);
\path[name path=DV2] (D) -- (V2);

\path[name intersections={of=BV1 and DV2}] (intersection-1);
\coordinate (C) at (intersection-1);

\coordinate (E) at (0,3);

\path[name path=Bup] (B) -- ++(0,\cubelength);
\path[name path=Dup] (D) -- ++(0,\cubelength);
\path[name path=EV1] (E) -- (V1);
\path[name path=EV2] (E) -- (V2);

\path[name intersections={of=Bup and EV2}] (intersection-1);
\coordinate (F) at (intersection-1);

\path[name intersections={of=Dup and EV1}] (intersection-1);
\coordinate (H) at (intersection-1);

\path[name path=FV1] (F) -- (V1);
\path[name path=HV2] (H) -- (V2);

\path[name intersections={of=FV1 and HV2}] (intersection-1);
\coordinate (G) at (intersection-1);

\foreach \x in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H} \fill (\x) circle (0.05) node[below right,circle] {\x};

\foreach \s\e in {A/B,D/A,A/E,B/F,D/H,E/F,F/G,G/H,H/E} \draw (\s) -- (\e);

\foreach \s\e in {B/C,C/D,C/G} \draw[densely dashed] (\s) -- (\e);

\foreach \p in {C,D,G,H} \draw[dotted] (\p) -- (V1);

\foreach \p in {B,C,F,G} \draw[dotted] (\p) -- (V2);

\path[name path=V1V2] (V1) -- (V2);

\draw[name intersections={of={Bup and V1V2},name=R}] (V2) -- (R-1);

\draw[name intersections={of={Dup and V1V2},name=L}] (V1) -- (L-1);

\draw[dotted] (L-1) -- (R-1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want (but with PSTricks)! I will, however, accept your answer if Herbert or someone else do not give a PSTricks solution.

Answer (score 8):

Tikz is a very powerful package with many examples available.
Have a look at [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cuboid/):

[image]

Is this something like what you are after?

Comment: My reading of the question is that Svend wants a PSTricks answer.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Exactly. I have no experience at all using TikZ so it is not an option for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jason Whyte: Yes it is but with PSTricks. I have never taken the time to learn TikZ.

Answer (score 8):

Here's something to get you started using the [`pst-solides3d`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pst-solides3d) package as requested.

[image]

I've borrowed experience from Werner's excellent answer to [pst-solides3d and hidden lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32211/pst-solides3d-and-hidden-lines)

Your first step in constructing the solid is to  specify its verticies:

```
  sommets= 
    0 0 0 
    3 0 0 
    3 3 0 
    0 3 0 
    0 3 1 
    0 0 1 
    3 0 1 
    3 3 1,
```

You can check if you got it right by using

```
  action=draw,num=all,show=all,
```

which gives

[image]

Finally you construct the solid by forming the faces- join the vertices together in an anti-clockwise direction

```
  faces={
    [2 1 0 3] % bottom face
    [6 5 0 1] % left face
    [7 6 1 2] % front face
    [4 7 2 3] % right face
    [3 0 5 4] % back face
    [7 4 5 6] % top face
    }]%
```

The complete MWE is below. See page 34-35 of [`pst-solides3d`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pst-solides3d) for a very similar example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=25 8 5,Decran=100}
\psSolid[object=new, 
  fillcolor=green!60,
  opacity=0.3,
  action=draw*,%num=all,show=all,
  sommets= 
    0 0 0 
    3 0 0 
    3 3 0 
    0 3 0 
    0 3 1 
    0 0 1 
    3 0 1 
    3 3 1,
  faces={
    [2 1 0 3] % bottom face
    [6 5 0 1] % left face
    [7 6 1 2] % front face
    [4 7 2 3] % right face
    [3 0 5 4] % back face
    [7 4 5 6] % top face
    }]% 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

And if you want to colour the sides, you can use `fcol`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=25 8 5,Decran=100,solidmemory}
\psSolid[object=new, 
  fillcolor=green!60,
  name=Mycube,
  opacity=0.3,
  action=none,%num=all,show=all,
  sommets= 
    0 0 0 
    3 0 0 
    3 3 0 
    0 3 0 
    0 3 1 
    0 0 1 
    3 0 1 
    3 3 1,
  faces={
    [2 1 0 3] % bottom face
    [6 5 0 1] % left face
    [7 6 1 2] % front face
    [4 7 2 3] % right face
    [3 0 5 4] % back face
    [7 4 5 6] % top face
    }]% 
    \psSolid[fcol=2 (Apricot)
                  3 (ForestGreen)
                  5 (WildStrawberry),
    object=load,load=Mycube,action=draw*]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks very promising. However, it does not seem to be in "true" perspective, i.e., have vanishing points (which I would like to mark and draw dotted lines from to each of the vertices). Am I mistaken about this?

Comment: @SvendMortensen can you meet me in chat?

Comment: Sure, if I figure out how to do that. :)

Comment: Here you go: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6166/how-can-i-draw-a-transparent-cube-in-3d-perspective?tab=general ... I hope this is correct; I have never used chat rooms here before.

Comment: I have updated my initial post with come code that, when complied, shows that I will like to achieve.

Comment: @SvendMortensen ok, I'll work on it later today- will post back if I make progress

Comment: @cmhughes: instead of defining points you can simply use the object `parallelepiped` with `a=3,b=3,c=1`

Comment: @Herbert could you post an answer? I'd vote for it :)

Comment: I already did :-)

Comment: @Herbert +1, brilliant (as always) :)